# Activity indicator not stopping when webview has finished loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview, indicator

Anyone have an idea why my activity indicator is not stopping when the webview has finished loading? Web view is delegated, `UIActivityIndicatorView` start animating etc, is in my code... ?

This is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var url = "http://apple.com"

func loadURL () {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadURL()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webview.delegate = self;
    }


func webviewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView){
activity.startAnimating()

    NSLog("The webview is starting to load")
    }

func webviewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){
    activity.stopAnimating()
    activity.hidden=true;
    NSLog("The webview is done loading")
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind the functions names! It's webView..., camel case :)

Comment: Dan is the winner! (voted.) Any time you have a delegate method, if the name or method signature is different from the definition of the delegate method it won't get called. This bites everybody at some point. Set a breakpoint in your delegate methods and make sure they are called (or use a log statement like you are doing.) If the method is not being called, try copy/pasting the method definition out of the docs or the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting "The webview is done loading"?. If not, probably the request it's taking a very long time to complete it.

However, you should implement `func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?)` to detect if there's any error and stop the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct answer is a probably combination of DAN's and iGongora's, plus a possible third reason.

The immediate problem is that even in a happy path scenario (where the webview finishes successfully) is that it should be the following (pay attention to the case of the function names web**V**iewDidStartLoad and web**V**iewDidFinishLoad

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activity.startAnimating()
    NSLog("The webview is starting to load")
}

 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activity.stopAnimating()
    activity.hidden=true;
    NSLog("The webview is done loading")
}
```

Additionally, if the `UIWebView` fails, you should also stop the spinner.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
    activity.stopAnimating()
    activity.hidden=true;
    print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
}
```

One other possible problem would be if you have not set the delegate properly. You can do it in the `viewDidLoad`, or in Interface Builder.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this in main queue so this will stop other wise not the code for this swift 4 and swift 3 is

```
 Dispatchqueue.main.async{
      activity.stopAnimating()
 }
```